# Blogger page title format

Tags: xml, blogs, blogger

Consider the following format for page title in blogger:**[blog Name].[page Name]**.
I used to place the following code in the title tags and without the title tags as cited in some programming site:

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;index&quot;'>
<title><data:blog.title/></title>
<b:else/>
<title><data:blog.pageName/></title>
</b:if>
```

The problem is that I get only **[page Name]** without the **[blog Name]**. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't include the blog name in the `else` part of the conditional. Looking at your sample you probably want this:

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;index&quot;'>
    <title><data:blog.title/></title>
<b:else/>
    <title><data:blog.title/><data:blog.pageName/></title>
</b:if>
```